# Include entire string when using re.findall to find string between characters

Tags: python, regex

When using re.findall like my example below is there a to include the final four characters (.JPG)? As they may be lower or uppercase I can't just stitch it together with another string and be certain it will be correct. (In reality it's a list of dozens/hundreds of JPGs, some uppercase and some lowercase.)

I actually found the answer to this about 2 weeks ago but have since lost it (despite a lot of Googling).

I've done a lot of searching/reading and apologize if this exact problem has been asked before.

```
import re

examplestring = '/home/folder/image.JPG 200x400 20/12/2018'

print(re.findall(r'^(.*?).jpg', examplestring, flags=re.IGNORECASE))
```

Actual output:

```
['/home/folder/image']
```

I'm wanting the output to be:

```
['/home/folder/image.JPG']
```

Comment: If that pattern is consistent, do the following: `examplestring = examplestring.split()[0]`

Comment: Have you tried _without_ the capture group: `re.findall(r'^.*?.jpg', examplestring, flags=re.IGNORECASE)`? It works just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, make sure to escape the dot since it's a special character in regex.

Either include `.jpg` in the group

```
^(.*?\.jpg)
```

or don't use a group at all

```
^.*?\.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks that's perfect, tutorials always use a group with characters on either side of it. I didn't realize you could do this, much more flexible and friendly than I thought.

Comment: I had the 'r' for raw string before it so I didn't need to escape the dot.

Comment: @AndrewOZ No, raw strings prevent backslashes from acting as special characters. They don't affect anything else.

Comment: @AndrewOZ No need to apologize! :)

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1

Maybe,

```
(?i)\S+\.jpg
```

or

```
(?i)\S+\.jpe?g
```

just in case, if we would have had `jpeg`, might simply work OK.

#### [RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/W5yhEF/1/)

We can include additional boundaries, if that'd be necessary, such as start anchor.

> Also, the expression does not work if there would be any space in the dir names or filenames.

---

### Method 2

If there would be horizontal spaces in the image path, then

```
(?i)^[^\r\n]+\.jpg
```

or

```
(?i)^[^\r\n]+\.jpe?g
```

would have been some options to explore.

#### [RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/4HFzZy/1/)

#### Test

```
import re

string = '''
/home/folder/image.JPG 200x400 20/12/2018
  /home/folder/image.jpg 200x400 20/12/2018
  /home/folder/image.jpeg 200x400 20/12/2018
'''

expression = r'(?i)\S+\.jpe?g'

print(re.findall(expression, string))
```

#### Output

```
['/home/folder/image.JPG', '/home/folder/image.jpg', '/home/folder/image.jpeg']
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/W5yhEF/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/W5yhEF/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: This definitely works but I don't understand how so I'll go with the answer above as it's easier to get my head around. Thanks a lot though.

Comment: @AndrewOZ `(?i)` is an embedded version of `re.IGNORECASE`. The main bit is different: `\S+` means "one or more non-whitespace characters" as opposed to `.*?` which means "the smallest amount of zero or more characters". I'm not sure why Emma changed it.

Comment: @Emma Ah, I see. It's really helpful to include info like that in the answer, along with any assumptions or inferences you make.

Comment: Cheers, so if there was a space in the image name or a directory name this wouldn't work?